# Is it possible to restore only new changes from latest PostgreSQL dump

Tags: postgresql, dump

Now to restore from the a back-up/dump takes about 20 minutes,

```
pg_restore  --create --exit-on-error --verbose  -U postgres --dbname=postgres  --verbose --clean -F directory mydb.dump
```

**Q:** Is it possible to restore **only new changes** (to save time) from latest PostgreSQL dump,
   whenever someone has changed the db or added new data?

--

*I know usually ppl use sql scripts and apply them on their db. But if there are not scripts. Because the db is altered from the outside.*

Comment: I don't think the dump stores any timestamps, so it doesn't know what data is "new". Also it doesn't store deleted data, so you cannot apply deletions from the "old" data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, pg_restore has no way of knowing what are new changes.  Perhaps it could rely on timestamps you keep inside your tables, but it wouldn't know how to do this, you would have to write code to teach it.

It sounds like what you really are looking for is to use a physical backup, and then WAL replay.

Comment: then I wonder if possible to generate the sql-piece on the fly for each db change that is applied on it. so latter it cold be applied over older one. i guess different question.. like event log. and apply it as db restore.

Comment: That sounds like you want logical replication.  There is built in logical replication with Publications and Subscriptions, but that is more for immediate replication, not saving up changes for future application.  So, perhaps "pg_recvlogical", although I think that that is more for testing and as an example than for actual production use.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for that in `pg_restore`, but from PostgreSQL v12 on you can use `pg_dump` with the options `--inserts --on-conflict-do-nothing`. Such a dump will restore only those rows that do not violate a primary key or unique constraint on the table to which you restore.

Comment: I think the OP wants the opposite of do-nothing - he wants to only apply the conflicting changes to speed up the loading of the dump.